# Apache License 2.0 compatibility with source code licensed under GPL 2 with classpath exception

Tags: licensing, gpl, apache-2.0

I am working on an open-source project that is governed by the Apache License 2.0, and I want to make use of Java source code from OpenJDK 11, which is governed by the GPL 2 license with classpath exception.

Although [this](https://www.apache.org/licenses/GPL-compatibility.html) page on the Apache site says that AL 2 is not compatible with GPL 1 and GPL 2, it does not say anything about GPL 2 with classpath exception.

My question is really an extension of this great [question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/119436/what-does-gpl-with-classpath-exception-mean-in-practice). Can source code under GPL 2 with classpath exception be used within a project that is under Apache License 2?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I modified and used GPL2 Code in my Apache 2 Open Source Project - can my Project be used commercially, closed source?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/7164/i-modified-and-used-gpl2-code-in-my-apache-2-open-source-project-can-my-projec)

Comment: In part, yes. Thanks @Martin_in_AUT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can source code under GPL 2 with classpath exception be used within a project that is under Apache License 2?

**No.**

The only way that code under the Apache 2 license and code under the GPLv2+Classpath can coexist in one application is when the GPLv2+Classpath code lives in a separate module that gets loaded via Java's Classpath mechanism.

In all other situations, the Classpath Exception does not kick in and the analysis for why the Apache and GPLv2 licenses are incompatible applies. And the result of incompatible licenses is that you can't use the software.

Comment: This helps a lot. Thanks for the explanation, Bart.
And by OpenJDK source code, I mean a few methods from the class' source code for which custom implementations are provided. So, in such a case, does the GPL v2 with Classpath exception apply at all?

Thanks again, as much as I'd want to upvote your answer, I don't have the reputation to.

Comment: @VaradG, yes, even when copying just a few lines you need to observe the GPL license.

Comment: Understood Bart, thank you!